# How do I replace text at PHP

Tags: php

I want to make "forum-like" system, for example I want to make text between * will be transformed into the text but between h1 tags, how do I tell str_replace or preg_replace that it must create first * into h1 and second * into /h1, with saving text between * and putting it between h1 tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**

This is simply a case of using regex to match the pattern required i.e. `*some text*` and capturing the *inner text*

```
\*(.*?)\*
\*         : Escaped asterisk; matches a literal asterisk
  (        : Start of capture group
   .+?     : Matches any character one or more times in a non-greedy manor
      )    : End of capture group
       \*  : Escaped asterisk; matches a literal asterisk
```

**Replace**

Then we can replace the entire pattern changing the asterisks for `<h1>` & `</h1>`.

```
<h1>$1</h1>
<h1>         : Opening tag
    $1       : Capture group content
      </h1>  : Closing tag
```

**Code Example**

```
$string = "*head* this is some text";

$string = preg_replace('/\*(.*?)\*/', "<h1>$1</h1>", $string);

echo $string;

// Output: <h1>head</h1> this is some text
```

Comment: And I have one more question, if I need to replace as many * as user want, I can just put preg_replace at foreach?

Comment: @Vadim It should replace all instances as is!